# Mongo: how to retrieve ONLY subdocs that match certain properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Having, for example, a collection named `test` and the following document is inside:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5692ac4562c824cc5167379f"),
    "list" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "elem1",
            "type" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "elem2",
            "type" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "elem3",
            "type" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "elem4",
            "type" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "elem4",
            "type" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Let's say I would like to retrieve a list of **only** those subdocuments inside `list` that match:

- `type = 2`.

I've tried the following **query**:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
    '_id': ObjectId("5692ac4562c824cc5167379f"),
    'list.type': 1
})
```

But the result I get contains *every* subdocument inside `list`, and I guess this is because inside `list` there are at least one document which's type *equals* 1.

Instead of that, the result I am interested to obtain would be **every subdocument inside `list` that matches `'list.type': 1`**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5692ac4562c824cc5167379f"),
    "list" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "elem1",
            "type" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "elem3",
            "type" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

...so `$`and `$elemMatch` is not what I am really looking for as they return just the first matching element.

Anyone knows how to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @user3100115 NOT REALLY, I don't want ONLY ONE element, I want ALL THE MATCHING elements!!!

Comment: Check the answers that used the `.aggregate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.myCol.aggregate([ 
                    { $unwind: "$list" }, 
                    { $match: { "list.type":1 } }, 
                    { $group: { "_id":"$_id", list: {$push:"$list"}} }
])
```